# Unit test cannot delete database due to open JDBC connection

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite, jdbc, junit

We're making a small Java app using unit test classes which may not be modified. The app uses an SQLite database, and one test class, DAOTest, tests the DAO class. When run individually, all of the tests in DAOTest are passed, however when run one after another only one is passed, the others fail.

**DAO.java:**

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DAO  {
    private Connection conn = null;
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";

    public DAO() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // methodA(), methodB(), ...
}
```

**DAOTest.java**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

public class DAOTest {
    DAO dao = null;

    /**/
    @Test
    void initDb() {
        if (dao != null) {
            dao.close();
        }

        File dbfile = new File("database.db");
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File srcfile = new File(classLoader.getResource("db/databaseToBeCopied.db").getFile());
        Boolean isDbDeleted = false;
        try {

            isDbDeleted = dbfile.delete();
            Files.copy(srcfile.toPath(), dbfile.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Database deleted: " + isDbDeleted);
        }

        dao = new DAO();
    }

    @Test
    void testA() {
        initDb();
        // Call dao.methodA()...
    }

    @Test
    void testB() {
        initDb();
        // Call dao.methodB()...
    }

}
```

I understand what is causing of the problem. `initDb()` is called at the start of every test, to copy `databaseToBeCopied.db` to `database.db`. The copy function expects the `database.db` file not to already exist, or it throws a `FileAlreadyExistsException`. Because the `dao` variable in `DAOTest.java` is a `non-static`attribute, it is null at every invocation of `initDb()`, so `dao.close()` will not be called, and the connection to the database will not get closed. This now disables the deletion of database.db, so the copy functions throws the exception, and the tests fail. I cannot modify the test class.

The only possible solution I could think of is to open and close the database connection in every single method of `DAO.java`, so the `close()` function would not be required. There are a couple of problems with this approach:

- I don't know how efficient this would be
- `DAO.java` methods can call each other, which might cause complications
- It seems like a bad practice at first sight

Could this be solved by another approach, perhaps with multi-threading? This is one of the topics we've shortly covered, however I'm not very familiar with it, so I don't know how, or if it could be done at all.

Comment: "using unit test classes which may not be modified" - Are you saying that you cannot change the existing unit test classes, even if they are poorly (or perhaps "sub-optimally") designed?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, exactly. It might be an oversight, or it possible that it's intentional and requires a workaround, especially if it's via multi-threading. However that's at best just an assumption.

Comment: It's a shame, really. The tests are supposed to support the core application code, not the other way around. However, you *could* modify the core DAO code to always open and close a connection. It sounds inefficient, but it could be okay if your main code used a connection pool. In fact, if this is a school exercise then perhaps that's what they're driving at.

Comment: You should address the underlying problem, that is that your tests don't properly handle resources, eg: you don't call `close()` on DAO after the test (don't forget to take exception into account) and the next test will create a different instance. If you can't change tests, then you have a big problem and you should address that (seriously: not being able to modify tests is extremely weird), trying to fix the problem of badly written tests in your underlying code is asking for problems.